# What's the name of this plant

Tags: identification, diagnosis, leaves

[image]

DID ANYONE KNOW THE NAME OF THIS LEAVES FROM THIS SKETCH?

Comment: If that card is something to do with the wedding or engagement of "I" and "L", box is an strange choice of plant to use for the decoration. In the UK it was traditionally associated with death and the underworld, and also with witchcraft!

Answer (score 1):

Buxus microphyllus is possible, but this is presumably an idealized representation of foliage that suits the design of the card or whatever it is, rather than a depiction of an actual plant.

Comment: I'm thinking more about Adiantum. OTOH I doubt that who did the design were an expert botanist, so I doubt the design is accurate (and there were also no reason to do it accurate)